# How to correct invalid body form

Tags: discord.py

I am trying to build a discord bot using slash commands. I am running into this error:

```
discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body
In name: String value did not match validation regex.
```

Code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord_slash import SlashCommand

client = commands.Bot(
    command_prefix='/',
    help_command=None,
    intent=discord.Intents.all()
)
slash = SlashCommand(
    client,
    sync_commands=True)

guild_ids = [
    0123456789
]

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("*throws banana*")

@slash.slash(
    name='Throw Banana',
    description='Throw a banana at an unsuspecting humanoid...',
    guild_ids=guild_ids)
async def throw_banana(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'*throws banana at {ctx.author}')

client.run(
    'token'
)
```

Token and guild_ids are changed for example.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that I incorrectly assumed 'name' and the function name itself could be different. They must be the same.

```
@slash.slash(
    name='throw_banana',
    description='Throw a banana at an unsuspecting humanoid...',
    guild_ids=guild_ids)
async def throw_banana(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'*throws banana at {ctx.author}')
```